# How to generate an HTML file every 10 seconds from a SSRS 2008 R2 report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 R2 without parameters that has to refresh every 10 seconds - a dashboard.

But I need to add some more HTML content because SSRS 2008 R2 doesn't support all HTML tags.

How can I have SSRS 2008 R2 generate a file every 10 secs with the HTML that I could then include in my "main"  HTML page?

Comment: out of intense curiosity, why are you generating this every 10 seconds?

Comment: a dashboard that pulls a stat file that is generated every 10 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a form in HTML and then consume the SSRS Web Service to get the info for the form.

It would be similar to this in HTML:

< FORM id="frmExample" action="http://(servername) /ReportServer/(path to report)" method="post" target="_self">

< input type="hidden" name="(VariableName)" value="(value)">

< /FORM>

For the update dashboard part I think you may be able to handle that on the HTML but am not certain even if you choose to refresh the report on the SSRS server if it will refresh your dependent object in the form.  You may have to try and see.  It is weird how you get to it but you click anywhere on the space outside the design viewer and then click F4 to get properties.  There is an 'AutoRefresh' property.  Set that to the duration in seconds you wish to autorefresh.

I got this from this book, but I have never done it except in a lab.

'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services' by Brian Larson

Comment: what would name and value be used for?

Comment: also: how does this form submit?

Comment: The input is if you have a variable in your report for input.  The form is doing a POST method to the HTML page from the SSRS Web Server.    The HTML is independent of the SSRS Front End but dependent on the Web Service to pull it's data for the form to display.